# How can I transfer an image from html to nodejs to use it with ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, ejs

I was trying to create a new website using nodejs and expressjs. Basically I have a page (/ home) where there is a form with an input file. I have already created the code to show the preview of the image once loaded ... what I would like to do is essentially transfer the "link" of the image to nodejs, where I will then take this "link" and insert it in the src of the img tag in the EJS end. can someone help me? thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using express  you can add this attribute to form tag `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Then your image will be sent from frontend . To receive the image in the server you need to configure a middleware called express-fileupload

```
var fileupload = require("express-fileupload");
```

then you can register the middleware by `app.use(fileupload());` in your app.js file

in your route file

```
router.post('/something', async (req, res) => {
let image=req.files.fieldName
}))
```

To save the image  here i am storing the image in server itself but this is not  recommended .
You want to rename the image with a connection . for eg the mongo document inserted id

```
image.mv('./public/images/foldername/' + id + '.jpg', (err) => {
  if (err) {
console.log(err)
  } else {
    res.redirect('/)
  }
})
```

once it is done when you submit your form you can see the uploaded image in your server /public/images/foldername .

To view in ejs you can basically loop through the mongo id or some connection that i have mentioned earlier